Read files in HDFS from Spark - RPC response exceeds maximum data length
Hi Im new to spark and im trying to access files from hdfs in spark-shell.
I wrote the following code from spark-shell
scala> val myfile = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9870/sample/demofile.txt")
val myfile: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = hdfs://localhost:9870/sample/demofile.txt MapPartitionsRDD[3] at textFile at <console>:1

scala> myfile.collect()

For this im getting following errors
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException: RPC response exceeds maximum data length
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$IpcStreams.readResponse(Client.java:1936)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveRpcResponse(Client.java:1238)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:1134)

Please help me to resolve the issue.
Is this configuration error or something else? please help out.

Please close spark-shell and reopen .. it should work.

@s.polam even after closing and reopen im getting same error. Is there any configuration files  need to be updated? I have modified .bashrc file with the following lines
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin
Other than this, is there any configuration files needed to be modified?
